# CURL uploads blank file by FTP

Tags: php, curl

I am using this curl script to try to upload user selected files by FTP. It uploads the files to the server but they are all blank. Why is this happening?

```
if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $localfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp-addy-here'.$_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
    curl_exec ($ch);
    $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
        if ($error_no == 0) {
            $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
        } else {
            $error = 'File upload error.';
        }
 } else {
        $error = 'Please select a file.';
 }

echo $error;
```

Comment: Removed html5 tag because it is not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 3, right now it says:

`$localfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];`

Change it to:

`$localfile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check if the initial file upload succeeded. Checking for the presence of the remote filename is **NOT** an indication that it got uploaded. The 100% reliable method to ensure the upload worked is

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  ... ftp stuff ...
} else {
    die("Upload failed with error code: {$_FILES['userfile']['error']}");
}
```

The codes/constants are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer but it's very valid point nevertheless